# GMP: Are self-assignments forbidden?

Tags: c, gmp

I'm using the GMP library for arbitrary precision in C.  All usage examples that I've seen seem to avoid self assignments such as:

```
Syntax : void mpz_add (mpz_t rop, const mpz_t op1, const mpz_t op2)

mpz_add(a, a, b); // Assign a+b to a
```

Is this usage allowed or should I only resort to assigning to a third variable?

Comment: What does the GMP documentation say about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with self-assignment as such. In fact, the [documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Variable-Conventions.html#Variable-Conventions) states exactly opposite. According to 3.4 *Variable Conventions*:

> GMP lets you use the same variable for both input and output in one
>   call. For example, the main function for integer multiplication,
>   mpz_mul, can be used to square x and put the result back in x with
>
> ```
>  mpz_mul (x, x, x);
> ```

Comment: The signature for multiplicaton is `void mpz_mul (mpz_t rop, const mpz_t op1, const mpz_t op2)`. I am confused as to how `op1` and `op2` can be `const` if doing `mpz_mul(x, x, x)` can change `x`.

Comment: @JustinRaymond: `mpz_t` is defined internally as one-element array, hence these parameters are passed effectively as pointers. The actual object is refenced by three different pointers. The first one has no `const` qualifier, thus it can be changed via _that_ pointer. This is analogous to situation such `int x = 100; const int* ptr1 = &x; int* ptr2 = &x; *ptr2 = 200;`. The `int` object can be modified _despite_ that `ptr1` pointer has `const` qualifier.